# What will happen if JVM heap memory is full and you are trying to create a new object

Tags: java

If JVM heap is full, and all objects are strong references, now if you will create a new object then what will happen and in which memory the object will be created. (not expecting OOM error)

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect an `OutOfMemoryError`?

Comment: The garbage collector kicks in.

Answer (score 4):

If there is not enough free space, the JVM runs the Garbage Collector (typically a "full" GC).  If there is *still* not enough free space after running the GC, the thread that was trying to `new` the object will throw an `OutOfMemoryError` exception.

- If the OOME is on the main thread and is not caught, the JVM will exit.
- If the OOME is caught or if it is not thrown on the "main" thread, the JVM will attempt to proceed.

Unwinding the stack to the catch point *may* make enough objects unreachable that the JVM is able to continue (after another GC).  However, when an OOME occurs, the recovery code typically cannot determine or undo the damage that may have occurred; e.g. objects that were not properly created, other threads that may have died with OOMEs.

Recovery from OOMEs is often problematic, and it is debatable whether you should try:

- You may not be able to recover properly.  The application / server / whatever may end up in a broken state.
- If the cause of the OOME is a memory leak, then it is liable to recur with increasing frequency.  It is better for the application to die and be restarted.
- If the cause of the OOME is that the JVM's memory is too small or the task is too large, then recovering and trying again typically won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#d5e25000):

> If evaluation of a class instance creation expression finds there is insufficient memory to perform the creation operation, then an `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown. This check occurs before any argument expressions are evaluated.

It even gives you a sample program that will throw the OOM...eventually:

> ```
> class List {
>     int value;
>     List next;
>     static List head = new List(0);
>     List(int n) { value = n; next = head; head = this; }
> }
> class Test {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         int id = 0, oldid = 0;
>         try {
>             for (;;) {
>                 ++id;
>                 new List(oldid = id);
>             }
>         } catch (Error e) {
>             List.head = null;
>             System.out.println(e.getClass() + ", " + (oldid==id));
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

On my system, it took a few minutes, but it got there in the end:

> ```
> $ javac Test.java 
> $ java Test
> class java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, false
> ```